# While loop stuck at the bottom even when the condition is still true

Tags: c, while-loop, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

I am using YOLO for object detection and wanted to edit the code files to run detection on all the images in a folder and I found this function [Github link to the function](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/64efa721ede91cd8ccc18257f98eeba43b73a6af/src/detector.c#L1603)

I edited the "test_detector" function as follows from [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/64efa721ede91cd8ccc18257f98eeba43b73a6af/src/detector.c#L1641):

```
while (1) {
    folder = opendir("./result_img/");
    char str1[100] = "./result_img/";
    while( (entry=readdir(folder)) != NULL)
    
    {
    if((strcmp(entry->d_name,".")==0 || strcmp(entry->d_name,"..")==0 || (entry->d_name) == '.' ) || (strcmp(entry->d_name,"Server_v1.py")==0))
    {
     printf(".");
     sleep(0.5);
     continue;
    }
    if (filename) {
        
        strcat(str1, entry->d_name);
        strncpy(input, str1, 256);
        closedir(folder);
        if (strlen(input) > 0)
            if (input[strlen(input) - 1] == 0x0d) input[strlen(input) - 1] = 0;
    }
    else {
        printf("Enter Image Path: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        input = fgets(input, 256, stdin);
        if (!input) break;
        strtok(input, "\n");
    
    }
    //image im;
    //image sized = load_image_resize(input, net.w, net.h, net.c, &im);
    image im = load_image(input, 0, 0, net.c);
    image sized;
    if(letter_box) sized = letterbox_image(im, net.w, net.h);
    else sized = resize_image(im, net.w, net.h);

    layer l = net.layers[net.n - 1];
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < net.n; ++k) {
        layer lk = net.layers[k];
        if (lk.type == YOLO || lk.type == GAUSSIAN_YOLO || lk.type == REGION) {
            l = lk;
            printf(" Detection layer: %d - type = %d \n", k, l.type);
        }
    }

    //box *boxes = calloc(l.w*l.h*l.n, sizeof(box));
    //float **probs = calloc(l.w*l.h*l.n, sizeof(float*));
    //for(j = 0; j < l.w*l.h*l.n; ++j) probs[j] = (float*)xcalloc(l.classes, sizeof(float));

    float *X = sized.data;

    //time= what_time_is_it_now();
    double time = get_time_point();
    network_predict(net, X);
    //network_predict_image(&net, im); letterbox = 1;
    printf("%s: Predicted in %lf milli-seconds.\n", input, ((double)get_time_point() - time) / 1000);
    //printf("%s: Predicted in %f seconds.\n", input, (what_time_is_it_now()-time));

    int nboxes = 0;
    detection *dets = get_network_boxes(&net, im.w, im.h, thresh, hier_thresh, 0, 1, &nboxes, letter_box);
    if (nms) {
        if (l.nms_kind == DEFAULT_NMS) do_nms_sort(dets, nboxes, l.classes, nms);
        else diounms_sort(dets, nboxes, l.classes, nms, l.nms_kind, l.beta_nms);
    }
    draw_detections_v3(im, dets, nboxes, thresh, names, alphabet, l.classes, ext_output, input);
    save_image(im, "predictions");
    if (!dont_show) {
        show_image(im, "predictions");
    }

    if (json_file) {
        if (json_buf) {
            char *tmp = ", \n";
            fwrite(tmp, sizeof(char), strlen(tmp), json_file);
        }
        ++json_image_id;
        json_buf = detection_to_json(dets, nboxes, l.classes, names, json_image_id, input);

        fwrite(json_buf, sizeof(char), strlen(json_buf), json_file);
        free(json_buf);
    }

    // pseudo labeling concept - fast.ai
    if (save_labels)
    {
        char labelpath[4096];
        replace_image_to_label(input, labelpath);

        FILE* fw = fopen(labelpath, "wb");
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < nboxes; ++i) {
            char buff[1024];
            int class_id = -1;
            float prob = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < l.classes; ++j) {
                if (dets[i].prob[j] > thresh && dets[i].prob[j] > prob) {
                    prob = dets[i].prob[j];
                    class_id = j;
                }
            }
            if (class_id >= 0) {
                sprintf(buff, "%d %2.4f %2.4f %2.4f %2.4f\n", class_id, dets[i].bbox.x, dets[i].bbox.y, dets[i].bbox.w, dets[i].bbox.h);
                fwrite(buff, sizeof(char), strlen(buff), fw);
            }
        }
        fclose(fw);
    }
    

    free_detections(dets, nboxes);
    free_image(im);
    free_image(sized);

    if (dont_show) {
        wait_until_press_key_cv();
        destroy_all_windows_cv();
    }

    if (filename) break;

    
    }
    sleep(1);
    printf("outside the loop");
    char newname[100];
   removeSubstrr(str1, "./result_img/");
    sprintf(newname, "./pfiles/%s",str1);
    //remove(input);
    printf("newname %s\n",newname);
    rename (input, newname);
    //sleep(1);
      
}

if (json_file) {
    char *tmp = "\n]";
    fwrite(tmp, sizeof(char), strlen(tmp), json_file);
    fclose(json_file);
}

// free memory
free_ptrs((void**)names, net.layers[net.n - 1].classes);
free_list_contents_kvp(options);
free_list(options);

int i;
const int nsize = 8;
for (j = 0; j < nsize; ++j) {
    for (i = 32; i < 127; ++i) {
        free_image(alphabet[j][i]);
    }
    free(alphabet[j]);
}
free(alphabet);

free_network(net);
```

}

When I am running the following code, it runs fine if the folder is not empty. once the folder is empty after sometime I get segmentation fault (core dumped) error. if i put "sleep(1)" at the end of first loop the code runs fine but every detection takes 1 second which is slow for the application.

I found that if i remove the line "if(filename)break;" the code stops at the end of the loop even when the folder is not empty.

filename is always true as it is passed through command line

Comment: `(entry->d_name) == '.'` will not work. You're comparing a string (an array actually, that will decay to a pointer) with a single character. That comparison will always be false.

Comment: As for the "stuck" loop, I recommend that you try to simplify your code, removing bit by bit until it starts working again. Then re-add the bits one by one until it stops working. Then you use a *debugger* to step through the code to find out why it doesn't work.

Comment: i think its working because if the folder is empty and if it encounters "." or ".." it prints "." as mentioned in the if statement

Comment: No, that check is not correct. You can't conclude that check is correct just because the whole conditional evaluates to true. `strcmp(entry->d_name,".")==0 ` part is correct, `(entry->d_name) == '.'` is wrong.

Comment: how to rectify that? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Regarding your problem, you have `closedir(folder)` inside the `readdir` loop, and it might be possible for the loop to continue after that. That's incorrect, you should only call `closedir(folder)` once the `readdir` loop have ended. I also see possible pointer usage (for example `input`) without checking that the pointer is not null. Or is initialized to begin with.